# How to change active worksheet in OpenPyXL with Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Please tell me how to make a changes in some worksheets Excel's file with OpenPyXl.
I have 4 worksheets (0, 1, 2, 3), and i need to make changes in last of 3 of them (1, 2, 3).
Im very new to Python, so sorry me.

Now i have this script which is make changes on 1 of the worksheets, i need him to make changes on worksheet number 1,2,,3 if we begin to count by zero.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font

# Import of required classes
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule  # Importing FormulaRule here

wb = load_workbook('uk-sheet.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# [A]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate Fill object

# Fill in red
fill_red = PatternFill(start_color='ee7811', end_color='ee7811', fill_type='solid')
# Fill in green
fill_green = PatternFill(start_color='11ee66', end_color='11ee66', fill_type='solid')

# Fill in yellow
fill_yellow = PatternFill(start_color='dfee11', end_color='dfee11', fill_type='solid')

# Generate Font object (bold/black)
font = Font(bold=True, color='000000')


# [C]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Apply conditional formatting rules to  range of cells
# Set the range for the conditional formatting
cf_range = '$A$2:$AT$42732'

# Add the rules for red fill
ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                              FormulaRule(
                                  formula=['IF($AR2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)'],
                                  stopIfTrue=None,
                                  fill=fill_red,
                                  font=font)
                              )

# Add the rules for green fill
ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                              FormulaRule(
                                  formula=['IF(AND($AR2>0.0001,$AR2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
                                  stopIfTrue=None,
                                  fill=fill_green,
                                  font=font)
                              )
# Add the rules for green fill
ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                              FormulaRule(
                                  formula=['IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2<4),TRUE,FALSE)'],
                                  stopIfTrue=None,
                                  fill=fill_yellow,
                                  font=font)
                              )
# Add the rules for red fill one more
ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range, FormulaRule(
    formula=['IF(AND($AR2=0, $AK2>3),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    stopIfTrue=None,
    fill=fill_red,
    font=font)
)

wb.save('uk-sheet2.xlsx')
```

I just read all the threads and can't find the answer.

Comment: The "active" worksheet is just convenient when working with a workbook in both openpyxl and Excel, where "active" is the worksheet in focus when the file is saved. It's almost always better to access worksheets directly by their title `wb["Sheet1"]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compact things a bit by creating a fill to formulas dictionary and use the one block to add the different cf rules to each sheet.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('uk-sheet.xlsx')

# Generate Fill object
fill_red = PatternFill(start_color='ee7811', end_color='ee7811', fill_type='solid')
fill_green = PatternFill(start_color='11ee66', end_color='11ee66', fill_type='solid')
fill_yellow = PatternFill(start_color='dfee11', end_color='dfee11', fill_type='solid')

font = Font(bold=True, color='000000')

cf_range = '$A$2:$AT$42732'

### Fill to formula dictionary
formula_dict = {
    fill_red: ['IF($AR2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)', 'IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2>3),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_green: ['IF(AND($AR2>0.0001,$AR2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_yellow: ['IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2<4),TRUE,FALSE)']
}

# Apply changes to each worksheet
### Select each sheet from 1 to 3 and each range from the list
for ws in wb.worksheets[1:4]:
    ### Extract the fill and formula(s)
    for colour_fill, formulas in formula_dict.items():
        for formula in formulas:  # For each formula in the fill 
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                          FormulaRule(
                                              formula=[formula],
                                              stopIfTrue=None,
                                              fill=colour_fill,
                                              font=font)
                                          )

# Save the modified workbook
wb.save('uk-sheet2.xlsx')
```